# Correcting for known imputation bias

Tags: multiple-regression, data-imputation, bias-correction, non-response, selection-bias

I have a survey sample which includes income values by type of income for a significant number of high-income households. Some of the income data is measured, i.e. present in the responses of the respondent. However, many high-income households do not answer the income questions. In these cases, income values in the reported data are imputed by a hot-deck-like procedure, i.e., income from a geographically and demographically similar household is used to replace the missing values. The households where imputation has been done are identified by data quality indicators published with the sample.

Based on a study which matched surveyed households from this data source to non-survey administrative records, which are believed to be more accurate and reliable, the imputation procedure referenced above has been shown to understate one important kind of income (labor income) of non-reporting households by about 20 percent. In addition, for high-income households (only), non-response has been increasing rapidly, potentially biasing the trend.

I would like to estimate a corrected value for other kinds of income – mainly capital and pension income – which were not matched by the matching procedure in the study just described (because they were not covered in the administrative source).

One approach to estimating such income is to take a subset of the sample with high incomes – in the top one-percent, say – exclude from that sample households for which the income is imputed, and then regress the log of non-wage income on the log of labor income and a vector of demographic (and maybe geographic) characteristics. I could then increase the imputed value of labor income of non-reporting households by 20 percent to correct for imputation bias, and use that corrected value as an independent variable in the labor to non-labor income relationship estimated by regression on the restricted sample.

I am worried about two possible sources of bias in using this procedure to estimate non-labor income in non-responding households. First, is there likely to be selection bias from limiting my sample to include only high-income households, and if so, how might I correct for it? This is my primary question an I will accept a good answer that addresses only this question.

Second, we know that the relationship between labor income and demographic characteristics is different for household that respond and those that do not. I don’t think this implies that the relationship between labor and non-labor income is different for reporting and non-reporting households, and the procedure I describe assumes that there is no difference. But I would welcome thoughts or comments as to whether this assumptions is plausible, and if not, how I might test for, estimate, or correct it.